# Chrome -- CSS -- Extra spacing

Tags: css, google-chrome, padding, space, extra

Can anyone look at this template and explain why only in Chrome that it adds a whole lot of extra space at the top of the page?

https://html5up.net/uploads/demos/verti

Update:

Actually, I just discovered that when I'm logged into my work Google account (in the browser as a whole), it adds the extra spacing at the top. When I'm just generally using Chrome (guest mode), it does NOT add the extra space at the top. All on the same computer at my house. Different results depending on if I'm logged in or not. Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: As mentioned below - teach yourself to use the Browser's developer tools. This will tell you which CSS is "active". It's quite likely that your work's Google account has custom CSS styling applied... this is not something we'll be able to confirm for you, however.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks!

Comment: Try using a css reset too like [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Answer (score 0):

Padding for the `#header-wrapper` element, has the following CSS (main.css - line 1839). This equates to a `padding-top: 66px` in Chrome...

```
#header-wrapper {
    padding: 4.5em 0 1em 0;
    padding-top: 4.5em;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

This would be simple to remove or override, if you needed to... e.g.

```
#header-wrapper {
    padding-top: 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: Did you see my additional information I just added about different results depending on if I'm logged into Chrome or not? I'm baffled!

Comment: I had a look with Firefox, and it actually has a padding top of `72px` (same CSS). You might want to familiarise yourself with the Browser's developer tools - it's quite easy to pickup.